# Google calendar links and wrong start/end times

Tags: wordpress, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have a rather strange problem. I'm trying to create URLs for Google Calendar items and everything is working fine, except when I add a timezone, the event start and end times are 5 minutes off. I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong. Example:

http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=Sample+Event&dates=20210511T1400/20210511T1500&ctz=America/New_York&location=&details=&sf=true

As you can you see from the URL, it should be 2PM and 3PM but when you actually go to the page, it's 5 minutes past the hour.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what is the problem here - why can't you set the time you want for the event?

Comment: Sure I can change the URL. But  I'm creating these URLs automatically based on ACF time and date fields. So I would need to include some math to correct the error. Can be done, but just find it weird why the difference between the URL and actual calendar entry. 1400 should be 2:00PM, not 2:05PM like it is now. Weirdly, if I take away the timezone setting `ctz=America/New_York`, time is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well finally found the answer. I was just missing the seconds from the time in the URL. That was messing it up. For example:

http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=Sample+Event&dates=20210511T140000/20210511T150000&ctz=America/New_York&location=&details=&sf=true